# -Y and read {src,dst} port and tshark

Tags: tcpdump, wireshark, tcp-ip, tshark

`tshark` get data from interface or pcap files. When it read data from interface, user has to write filter with `-f` (accortding to `pcap-filter(7)`) and when read from file user has to write filter with `-Y` (according to `wireshark-filter(4)`)

**My scenario:**

I have to read pcap files, So I have to use `wireshark-filter` syntax.
I have src address, dst address, src port and dst port. But I don't know type of session(TCP or UDP).
wireshark syntax has the following options for port:

```
tcp.dstport
tcp.srcport 
udp.dstport
udp.srcport
tcp.port 
udp.port
```

I don't know my packets are TCP or UDP, and I need to write filter according to dst port and src port.

How to implement with `tshark` and `-Y`?

Answer (score 0):

You can [build a display filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) (-Y option) using an `or` logical operator to take count of UDP and TCP packets.

For example:

```
udp.srcport=8899 or tcp.srcport=8899 or udp.dstport==7788 or tcp.dstport==7788
```